# When Excel refresh, Access front end form does not work

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have linked Excel to Access back end database through Excel (get external data - From Access). When I key in data to the form in the Access front end, I went to double check in the Excel if it appear. It appear when I refresh, however when I return to Access front end and click the form, the form becomes blank.

Is there any solution or a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you are writing data to excel sheet from Access using linked table?

Comment: You are entering data into Access table and Excel pulls data from that table? What version of Access? Are you able to have both files open at same time? Why is Excel involved?

Comment: I'm keying in data in to the form of the access and the data that is stored in the back end of the database is exported out to excel. I'm able to open both at once and it is working fine until i refresh in excel, this causes the form to go blank when i click a button which redirect me to the form.

Comment: I'm using both version 2013